# BackColor property not changing properly in code. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Intermediate C# dev here. Trying to transition into game programming by writing a simple Simon clone (private learning only, I do not own any copyrights or intend to distribute/sell) and I'm stuck.

Here's a link to the full code thus far: [Simon](https://github.com/Sylverac/Simon/blob/master/Simon/frmMain.cs)

The problem lies in the `PlayTile()` method below:

```
private void PlayTile(Button btnColorOfTile, Color lightedTileColor, SoundPlayer tileSoundPlayer, Color originalTileColor)
    {
        // ***BUG03***
        TilePress(btnColorOfTile, lightedTileColor, tileSoundPlayer);
        // Small pause so tile can be lit before instantly changing back
        Thread.Sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
        TileRelease(btnColorOfTile, originalTileColor, tileSoundPlayer);
        // Small pause between each tile play so that you can distingish multiple plays of the same tile.
        Thread.Sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
    }
```

This is *supposed* to "light" up the tile by changing the `BackColor` property, pause for a half second (`SLEEP_TIME`is set to 500ms) while playing the tile's sound, and change the `BackColor` back to the normal color.

The sound plays properly with the pause and everything, but the tiles are not changing color. I change the `BackColor` property in `TilePress()` and change it back in `TileRelease()` which is called in the MouseUp and MouseDown for the tile's event handlers and it works just fine.

Any ideas why `PlayTile()` is working for sound but not changing the `BackColor` property?

Also, if you see any glaring mistakes in the code, please let me know. This is all about learning for me so constructive criticism is desired.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You block the UI thread with `Thread.Sleep(SLEEP_TIME);`. Use **Timer**. (or `await Task.Delay(SLEEP_TIME)`)

Comment: I know about `Thread.Sleep()` blocking UI action. In this case, that behavior is wanted (the player does not have control, the computer is showing the player the pattern to mimic). I want the program to "light" the tile, pause for a half second and change the `BackColor` back. I have not used `await Task.Delay()`, let me look into that. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Have you tried to call Invalidate(); after setting the color to the form?

Comment: I have not, let me look up what `Invalidate()` does. Thanks.

Comment: @Sylverac I don't think we are talking the same. When I say *blocking*, it means your form can not process any window messages like keyboard, mouse, move, paint etc. It is a *"Not Responding"* state and not a desired behavior.

Comment: @EZI good call. I was able to get the tile to change the Tile's `BackColor` by changing the `PlayTile()` method to `async` and changing `Thread.Sleep(SLEEP_TIME);` to `await Task.Delay(SLEEP_TIME)` per your suggestion. However, instead of now playing the pattern in order one at a time, all tiles play at once when pressing the `New Game` button.

Comment: Now you can change your methods signature from `private void PlayTile` to `async private Task PlayTile` and *await* it in your main loop.

Comment: @EZI I don't have a main loop. I'm using the winform events to drive the flow of this game.

I guess I need to do some more research on `await Task.Delay` and `async` methods. Thanks for your help, I'll post another comment here if I run into problems again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread.Sleep blocks your UI thread(this means your form can not process any window messages like keyboard, mouse, move, paint etc. It is a "Not Responding" state and not a desired behavior).

You can use *async/await* instead.

Example:

```
async Task PlayTile()
{
    this.BackColor = Color.Red;
    await Task.Delay(500);
    this.BackColor = Color.White;
    await Task.Delay(500);
}

async private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        await PlayTile();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you absolutely have me on the right path, I'm just having problems implementing it.

Comment: I added an Update with further questions above. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Disregard, I got it figured out. I needed to add an await to all calls to the `PlayTile()` Task as well. Works perfectly now. Thanks!